# Autocomplete add source file from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have found some code which working with autocomplete. Now I want add my source data with multiple array. How can I do that?

```
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VZQGw/)

Comment: `[].push.apply(aTags, bTags)`

Comment: Where I am add this code? Can you edit on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked jsfiddle,
the `#selLanguage` is already populated with values.
If I understand correctly,
you want to replace those values with the concatenation of two arrays.
Here's the relevant part from a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t7jgtgs/1/):

```
$(function() {
    var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];
    var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];

    var $langs = $("#selLanguage");
    $langs.empty();
    $.each(aTags.concat(bTags), (k, v) => $langs.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", v).text(v)));
    $langs.combobox();
});
```

Comment: Can you show that in two input field and remove unnecessary code. Also show two different message if not match data. please check https://jsfiddle.net/Sakib00123/7jhdk00h/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` two array like this.

```js
var aTags = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];
var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];
var cTags=$.merge( aTags,bTags );
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: cTags
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
```

Comment: its not working like demo. Demo code has change event.

Comment: I want  all condition is working like demo, just change the source method option to array